# calling gnu makefiles from ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, makefile, rake

calling the command "make" within a directory where a gnu makefile is placed is done easily within a batch script using just the command:

```
make
```

Is there a way to execute the command "make" from a ruby script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a make file using ruby

mkmf.rb is used by ruby C extensions to generate a Makefile which will correctly compile and link the C extension to ruby and a third-party library.

```
create_makefile('test/foo', 'test')
```

> That will set the target_prefix in the generated Makefile to “test”.
>   That, in turn, will create the following file tree when installed via
>   the make install command: /path/to/ruby/sitearchdir/test/foo.so

More on it [MKMF](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html)

I you want to execute any commands use [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system)

```
system("make")
```

Comment: That's OK, but I need to implement a function in ruby which goes into directories where gnu makefiles are placed and than execute the gnu makefiles. The makefiles already exists there.

Comment: No, the gnu makefiles already exists in some directories. I would like just to call "make" from an ruby script